# Is the BTC-e shutdown legal?

Tags: exchanges, legal, btce, money-laundering, fincen

The FinCen, dependent of the Deparment of Treasury shut down the BTC-e exchange [and prosecuted for](https://www.fincen.gov/news/news-releases/fincen-fines-btc-e-virtual-currency-exchange-110-million-facilitating-ransomware):

- Violation of anti-money laundering (AML) laws;
- Acts of money laundering such as the [MtGox scandal](https://bravenewcoin.com/news/btc-e-indicted-for-laundering-mtgox-funds-fined-110-million/) related with BTC-e
- Requirements to register the exchange with the FinCen

As we know, BTC-e is based in Russia and has no legal obligation with the United States, as far I know and researched about the topic. In the statement previously cited, said:

> Regardless of its ownership or location, the company was required to comply with U.S. AML laws and regulations as a foreign-located MSB including AML program, MSB registration, suspicious activity reporting, and recordkeeping requirements.

So, in short: Is it legal that the US law enforcement close a Russian exchange?

Comment: Does not matter if it's legal. Important is that it's possible. Interesting is who will collect 110M$ fine